# The type or namespace Xrm could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

`public class CrmData : DataService<Xrm.XrmServiceContext>`

I get the error `The type or namespace Xrm could not be found` on the above pasted line. I am building a portal for Dynamics CRM 2011.

Things I have done:

- I have checked my target framework. It is .Net 4.0
- Changing the Framework from 4.0 ->3.5 -> 4.0 did not work as
  suggested by many others.
- `Microsoft.xrm.sdk` is already referenced.

Plus here is my Web.config with the relevant part

```
<microsoft.xrm.client>
<contexts>
  <add name="Xrm" type="Xrm.XrmServiceContext, WebApplication1"/>
</contexts>
</microsoft.xrm.client>
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the context using the `CrmSvcUtil.exe` included inside the SDK.

More information here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx

Comment: already did that. I have included it in App_Code folder of my solution